# Detecting a failed Laravel migration in a automated script on Bamboo CD

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, continuous-deployment, bamboo

I've a deployment pipeline for as Laravel application (on Atlassian Bamboo). Unfortunately, when a migration fails during the deployment, artisan migrate doesn't return a proper exit code that would allow the deployment to be flagged as failed.

Does someone have a good solution to this problem?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

I'm on Laravel v7.17.2.

error log from bamboo on the latest of this error

```
build   25-Jun-2020 08:44:41    Migrating: 2020_06_17_179512_create_invoice_payment_creditor_type_qrb
build   25-Jun-2020 08:44:41    
build   25-Jun-2020 08:44:41    In 2020_06_17_179512_create_invoice_payment_creditor_type_qrb.php line 52:
build   25-Jun-2020 08:44:41                                                
build   25-Jun-2020 08:44:41      Creating default object from empty value
```

Comment: which version of laravel you are using? will you please paste the output of the failed migration ?

Comment: I'm on laravel v7.17.2. I added the log from the latest failure in the question. Is laravel supposed to return a failure code? The error might be with Bamboo (the deployment software). Thanks

Comment: Please paste the content of 2020_06_17_179512_create_invoice_payment_creditor_type_qrb.php file

Comment: I don't need help to fix the migration, I already did so. My problem is only that the migration failure does not stop the deployment script. I doubt the content of the migration will help in any way.

Comment: Either you have to make sure the `migrate` doesn't fail (there are `...IfExists...` checks available) or you have to do some magic with `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php` and recreate your own migrate command. As commands only return 0 (for good) or 1 (something went wrong) and that leaves you with very few options.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitri, I've found the solution thanks to you. I was wrongly assuming that Laravel wasn't returning a correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake while building the deployment pipeline on Bamboo. I ran multiple commands on a single ssh task which means the return code of the migrate command (which wasn't the last command of the task) didn't fire an error. I now run each commands in a separate ssh task.

It seams obvious to me now.